# How to merge master into an issue when a directory in master has been renamed?

Tags: git, merge

I have a master branch and an issue branch that that look like this:

```
C0---C1---C2---C4--->(main)
            \
             \
              C3--->(iss1)
```

In `main`, the directory 'data' has been moved into 'src' in C4.
So the path to `data` is now `src/data`.

In `iss1`, C3 adds `data/artifact.cpp` (and 15 other files).

Now I want to update `iss1` by merging in C4 from `main`, and continue working on it.

When I merge `main` into `iss1` I get messages such as:

`CONFLICT (file location): 'data/artifact.cpp' added in HEAD inside a directory that was renamed in main, suggesting perhaps be moved to src/data/artifact.cpp`

How should I proceed so that my commit tree looks like this:

```
C0---C1---C2---C4--->(main)
            \     \
             \     \
              C3---C5--(iss1)
```

Comment: By staying on your `iss1` branch and use `git rebase master`

Comment: Resolve the conflicts with `git mv data/artifact.cpp src/data/`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you choose to rebase 'iss1' onto 'main' with:

```
git checkout iss1
git rebase main
```

You then get the conflicts due to the directory rename.

Type `git status`
This shows the files that need committing while rebasing 'iss1' on 'main'.

The status should show the instructions you require to resolve the conflicts.
In this case we type:

```
git add src/data/artifact.cpp
```

Alternatively:

```
git add src/data/*.cpp
```

Once all the conflicted files have been resolved, you can continue the rebase with:

```
git rebase --continue
```

When prompted, update the rebased commit.

With the rebased `iss1` branch, you can then update the remote `iss1` branch with:

```
git push --force
```

This of course assumes no one else is working on `iss1`!